# calculate multiplication factor to go from 1 to 100 in y attempts

Tags: python

I have `totalnumberofdays` and  `percentage on day 1`.  I have to incrementally grow the `currentpercentage` every day so that it reaches `100 percent` on `day n`

For ex:

If `totalnumberofdays` = 7, `percentage on day 1` = 1

`currentpercentage` would be equal to `percentage on day 1` the first day and then needs to grow incrementally.

```
Day 1   1 percent
Day 2   2 percent
Day 3   5 percent
Day 4   10 percent
Day 5   20 percent
Day 6   50 percent
Day 7   100 percent
```

How should `currentpercentage` be calculated for each day.

Comment: It would just be 100 / 7 wouldn't it? Does it need to ~double each time? What's the pattern there?

Comment: what kind of growth do you  want? Exponential? Linear? Logarithmic? Something different?

Comment: Your example is exponential-ish.

Comment: @Selcuk Yes, that works. It does not have to be exact. Just that it should reach 100% on day n. and grow each day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a little bit up, the exponential part is not 100% correct, since it assumes an exponential raise without adjusting to the percentage rate of day 1, but since you weren't sure about how it is supposed to raise in the first place I hope it is enough.

```
def linear_growth(n_days, percentage_on_day_1):
    days = [percentage_on_day_1]
    remaining_percent = 100-percentage_on_day_1
    percent_per_day = remaining_percent / (n_days-1)
    for i in range(1, n_days):
        days.append(days[i-1]+percent_per_day)
    return days

def exponential_growth(n_days, percentage_on_day_1):
    days = [percentage_on_day_1]
    base = (100-percentage_on_day_1)**(1/(n_days-1))
    for i in range(1, n_days):
        days.append(percentage_on_day_1 + base**i)
    return(days)

print(linear_growth(7, 10))
print(exponential_growth(7, 10))
```

Output:

```
#Linear:
[10, 25.0, 40.0, 55.0, 70.0, 85.0, 100.0]

#Exponential:
[10, 12.116932863025458, 14.481404746557164, 19.486832980505138, 30.082988502465085, 52.51433834863077, 99.99999999999999]
```

Comment: I get base =1 in exponential_growth function and then output is: [10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11] @LeoE

Comment: Instead of `**` maybe try the `pow(base, exponent)` function, might fix the problem, it is working for me however or `float(1/(n_days-1))` might fix it aswell

Comment: In the exponential growth function, what is exponential is the difference from the initial value, not the percentage value itself, which is something different. To have a *constant growth rate* each day, then the base should be `(100/percentage_on_day_1)**(1/(n_days-1))` and the value computed as `percentage_on_day_1 * base**i` (or incrementally).
In case the offset exponential is really what you want, then I'd suggest to fix the continuity at 0 using `base = (101-percentage_on_day_1)**(1/(n_days-1))` and `percentage_on_day_1 - 1 + base**i` for the value.

Answer (score 2):

Linear:

```
step = 100/7
for i in range(1, 8):
    print("Day {}".format(i), round(step*i))
```

Output:

```
Day 1 14
Day 2 29
Day 3 43
Day 4 57
Day 5 71
Day 6 86
Day 7 100
```

Exponential:

```
step = 100**(1/7)
for i in range(1, 8):
    print("Day {}".format(i), round(step**i))
```

Output:

```
Day 1 2
Day 2 4
Day 3 7
Day 4 14
Day 5 27
Day 6 52
Day 7 100
```

Edit: The following will let one set an arbitrary initial (day 1) value with an exponential increase:

```
initial = 10
days = 7
step = (100-initial)**(1/(days-1))
print("Day 1", initial)
for i in range(1, days):
    print("Day {}".format(i+1), initial+round(step**i))
```

Example output:

```
Day 1 10
Day 2 12
Day 3 14
Day 4 19
Day 5 30
Day 6 53
Day 7 100
```

Comment: Would it be better to set `step = 100/totalnumberofdays`. and `for i in range(1, totalnumberofdays)` It seems the question implies variables set, where it would allow for multiple lengths, instead of only 7?

Comment: @Simrankaur Updated the answer.

Comment: @Selcuk: Output that I get with your update does not match the output you have. ('Day 1', 10)
('Day 2', 11.0)
('Day 3', 11.0)
('Day 4', 11.0)
('Day 5', 11.0)
('Day 6', 11.0)
('Day 7', 11.0)

Comment: @Simrankaur You seem to be using Python 2.x, which has a different division operator. Try initialising the values as floats (i.e. `10.0` instead of `10` etc) in that case. Python 2.x is nearing (April 2020) end of life, by the way.